# Why not use <progress> for a gauge and not <meter> for progress?

Tags: html, progress-bar

In [here](https://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/tag_meter.asp) and [here](https://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/tag_progress.asp), they say (first about the :

> The <progress> tag is not suitable for representing a gauge (e.g. disk
> space usage or relevance of a query result). To represent a gauge, use
> the <meter> tag instead.

> Note: The <meter> tag should not be used to indicate progress (as in a progress bar). For progress bars, use the <progress> tag.

But they don't give any justification as to **why** they should not be used for those purposes respectively. Is there any reason for it?

Comment: I think its mostly just semantics. The [HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-progress-element)  says the same thing: "The progress element is the wrong element to use for something that is just a gauge, as opposed to task progress. For instance, indicating disk space usage using progress would be inappropriate. Instead, the meter element is available for such use cases."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<progress>` and `<meter>` are [semantic elements](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp) and are meant to make it easier for people using [screen readers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_reader) to use your website.

[`<progress>`](https://htmlreference.io/element/progress/) is for representing the progress of a task. Use it when some action is occurring, especially if the user may be waiting for the action to complete.

[`<meter>`](https://htmlreference.io/element/meter/) is for other uses like showing capacity. Use it when there is no action occurring.

If you use the wrong semantic element, screen readers may make your website even more unusable than if you had stuck to the basic HTML elements.